# How to make this ball spawn in the middle instead at the side? MonoGame in VisualStudio

Tags: visual-studio, monogame

Trying to create a simple breakout game, I've written all the code, except i dont understand why the ball is on the side of the screen boundaries instead of on top the paddle(player).

[Breakout game, ball on side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uy5q.png)

```
class Ball
{
    int Width => texture.Width;
    int Height => texture.Height;


    public Rectangle BoundingBox =>
        new Rectangle((int)position.X, (int)position.Y, Width, Height);

    Texture2D texture;
    Vector2 position;
    Vector2 speed;

    public void SetStartBallPosition(Rectangle rec)
    {

        position.X = rec.X + (rec.Width - Width);
        position.Y = rec.Y - Height;

        if (Game1.RandomNumber.Next(0, 2) < 1)
        {
            speed = new Vector2(-200.0f, -200.0f);
        }
        else
        {
            speed = new Vector2(200.0f, -200.0f);
        }


    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch sb)
    {
        sb.Draw(texture, position, Color.White);
    }

    public void Update(GameTime gt)
    {
        position += speed * (float)gt.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

        if (position.X + Width > Game1.ScreenBounds.Width)
            speed.X *= -1;
            position.X = Game1.ScreenBounds.Width - Width;

        if (position.X < 0)
        {
            speed.X *= -1;
            position.Y = 0;
        }

        if (position.Y < 0)
        {
            speed.Y *= -1;
            position.Y = 0;
        }
    }
```

TL;DR.

My ball spawns at the side instead of middle.

Thanks for Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `SetStartBallPosition(Rectangle rec)`, You've set the ball position at the full width of the boundary box, minus the full width of the ball:

```
position.X = rec.X + (rec.Width - Width);
```

Assuming that `rec` is empty, then in order to get the center, you need to divide both width's there in half. Like this:

```
position.X = rec.X + (rec.Width/2 - Width/2);
```

Be aware that when dividing, that they shouldn't have decimals.

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Hi, tried it already the ball is still on the right hand side of the screen :/

Comment: Edit: hmm no matter what i change in the `SetStartBallPosition` The ball is still on the right hand side, it just changes slightly, it keeps bouncing off of the paddle and stops at the red brick, then when i change it back it breaks it and goes to touch the top of the window and goes back, other time it stopped at blue brick. :O

Comment: I've looked back at the code and it seems that I've mixed up your variables. Try using `position.X = Game1.ScreenBounds.Width/2 - Width/2;` In the `SetStartBallPosition`. I'm not exactly sure what's going on with the rest though, but I'll only answer the current question.

Comment: Hey Steven, i fixed it today, the error was the order that the files were loaded in, ball.Draw, such a small error and so much time spent on looking for it, It's Fixed now, as well as the ball not bouncing off of the screen and just sticking to right side of it!

Thanks a lot though!

Comment: Glad to hear that it's fixed again. And I agree, sometimes even the smallest mistakes can take so much to fix again. And at the same time, a huge error could all be caused by a single mistake as well. But looks like it's all good now, Good luck further on!